# Content type with template from different site collection

Tags: content-type, site-collection, template

is it possible to use a Content type with a template from different site collection? The reason to do it is to not copy all the future templates to hundreds of site collections.

It seems it is possible to create such content type, but there are troubles with using it?? - I successfully created such a content type pointing to an attachment to a different site collection (the path start with "`/sites/and so on...`") but when attempted to create a document it looked like nothing happened - no error message for end-user, though 
Javascript console end up with 400 (Bad Request) inside  `spoapp-cxxxxx.js` around the `CreateDocumentAndGetEditLink()` function.

BTW. I was logged as site administrator of botch site collections. I also tried to set rights in the list containing items with template attachment to everyone, but it did not seem to solve this problem.

(Of course, since the template is taken from list inside off the current site, everything works)

I am beginner on Sharepoint, so I don't know, whether it is a problem with rights or it is not supported or it is a bug?

Thanks in advance,
Mojmir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To share Content Types between Site Collections, you usually implement a Content Type Hub. The CT Hub publishes Content Types, which other Site Collections can subscribe to. That way the get the same GUID and template to use across Site Collections.

See: [Create Content Type Hub in SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/create-content-type-hub-in-sharepoint-2013/)